# c++ overloading global delete is not working on VSCode c/c++ extension

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a school project about overloading the global new/delete, and was having problems with the default operator delete being called instead of my overloaded version. Originally I thought it was a problem with my code, but I installed Dev-C++ and the overloaded operator was called successfully. This is the code I used for testing (not my project code, I got this from here:
https://thispointer.com/overloading-new-and-delete-operators-at-global-and-class-level/).

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
// Overloading Global new operator
void* operator new(size_t sz)
{
  void* m = malloc(sz);
  std::cout<<"User Defined :: Operator new"<<std::endl;
  
  return m;
}
// Overloading Global delete operator
void operator delete(void* m)
{
  std::cout<<"User Defined :: Operator delete"<<std::endl;
  free(m);
}
// Overloading Global new[] operator
void* operator new[](size_t sz)
{
  std::cout<<"User Defined :: Operator new []"<<std::endl;
  void* m = malloc(sz);
  return m;
}
// Overloading Global delete[] operator
void operator delete[](void* m)
{
  std::cout<<"User Defined :: Operator delete[]"<<std::endl;
  free(m);
}
class Dummy
{
public:
  Dummy()
  {
    std::cout<<"Dummy :: Constructor"<<std::endl;
  }
  ~Dummy()
  {
    std::cout<<"Dummy :: Destructor"<<std::endl;
  }
};
int main()
{
  int * ptr = new int;
  delete ptr;
  Dummy * dummyPtr = new Dummy;
  delete dummyPtr;
  int * ptrArr = new int[5];
  delete [] ptrArr;
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints all statements in Dev-C++, and all statements except "user-defined :: operator delete" are printed in VSCode.

My question is what could I try to find the origin of this problem? Should I re-install the c++ addon on VSCode? Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: `operator delete[]` needs to be `noexcept` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I've concluded that there is a bug in the VSCode c/c++ extension. I installed visual studio and ran the code there, and it worked fine. I also spoke with a classmate using the c/c++ extension, and she was having the same problem I was. Now that we have both switched, the problem has disappeared.